# .Type does not have a member named "x" when trying to get variable value in Struct(Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift

I am currently working on an app and I am having an issue. When the user login the webservice, if the login is successful the server responds with JSON, where we use the "firstName" and "SecondName" to then create our "User" which is a struct defined in another file called User.swift . Then, what I want to do is user the "firstName" that has been given to the "User struct" as a UILabel in my homepageview that comes after a successful login. when I try to give my label User.prenom(which is firstName in french) I get the error: User.type does not have a member called...

Here is my code:

the client file where the Login Method is defined:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

private let _instance = Client()

class Client {
    // Router is used to do a request to the server.
    private enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    private static let baseURL =  "https://mobile.uqam.ca/portail_etudiant/"

        // stores the authentication token.
         static var code_perm: String?
         static var nip:String?

        // Login request.
        case Login(String, String)


        // URLRequestConvertible protocol.
        var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
            // Returns the path, http method and parameters for the  request.
            var (path: String, method: Alamofire.Method,  parameters: [String: AnyObject]) = {
                switch self {
                case .Login (let code_perm, let nip):
                    let params: [String: AnyObject] = [
                        "code_perm": code_perm,
                        "nip": nip,
                        ]
                    return ("proxy_dossier_etud.php", .POST, params)


                }
            }()

            // Setup the URLRequest.
            let url = NSURL(string: Router.baseURL)
            let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
            urlRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue
            if let code_perm = Router.code_perm {
                if let nip = Router.nip{

                parameters["nip"] = nip
                parameters["code_perm"] = code_perm
                }
            }

            let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL

            return encoding.encode(urlRequest, parameters: parameters).0
        }
    }

    // Singleton
    class var sharedInstance: Client {
        return _instance
    }
    private init() {}



    // Login logs in the user with his email and password.
    func login(code_perm:String, nip:String, callback:(LoginResponse?) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(Router.Login(code_perm, nip)).responseJSON { (_, _, data, error) in
            if(error != nil) {
                callback(nil)
                return
            }

            var json = JSON(data!)

            let prenom = json["socio"]["prenom"].stringValue
            let nom = json["socio"]["nom"].stringValue

            Router.code_perm = code_perm
            Router.nip = nip

            callback(LoginResponse(
                user: User(prenom: prenom,nom: nom)
            ))
        }
    }
}
```

the loginViewController where the login function is called

```
    import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var LoginScreenImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var codeTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var nipTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var loadingLogin: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    let client = Client.sharedInstance

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        LoginScreenImage.image = UIImage(named: "UQAMLOGO")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


        @IBAction func connect() {
        let code_perm = codeTextField.text
        let nip = nipTextField.text
        self.loadingLogin.startAnimating()

        if code_perm != "" && nip != "" {
            client.login(code_perm, nip: nip, callback: { (response) in
                if let response = response {

                        self.loadingLogin.stopAnimating()
                        let homeViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as HomeViewController

                        self.showViewController(homeViewController, sender: self)

                } else {
                    self.loadingLogin.stopAnimating()
                    let badLogin = UIAlertController(title: "Échec de connexion", message: "La combinaison du code permanent et du nip n'est pas bonne", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    let reessayer = UIAlertAction(title: "Réessayer", style: .Default, handler: { (reessayer) -> Void in
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true , completion: nil)
                    })
                    badLogin.addAction(reessayer)

                    self.presentViewController(badLogin, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
            })
        }
    }


}
```

the User.swift while where the user struct is

```
    import Foundation

struct User {
    var prenom :String
    var nom: String

}

struct LoginResponse {

    var user: User
}
```

and finally the HomePageViewController where I try to give the value to my label:

```
import UIKit


class HomeViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var schedule: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var courses: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var email: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var grades: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var bienvenueLabel: UILabel!



    let client = Client.sharedInstance

    override func viewDidLoad() {



        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        schedule.image = UIImage(named:"schedule")
        courses.image = UIImage(named: "courses")
        email.image = UIImage(named:"mail")
        grades.image = UIImage(named:"grades")
        bienvenueLabel.text = User.prenom


    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Thanks everyone for the help and have a great day/night

Charles

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the class instead of an instance. Instead, you should pass the response instance to your `HomeViewController`:

```
class HomeViewController : .. {
  // ...
  var loginResponse : LoginResponse
  // ...

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ...
    bienvenueLabel.text = loginResponse.user.prenom
  }
}

  // ...
  client.login(code_perm, nip: nip, callback: { (response) in
            if let loginResponse = response as LoginResponse {

                    self.loadingLogin.stopAnimating()
                    let homeViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as HomeViewController

                    homeViewController.loginResponse = loginResponse
                    // assign your instance ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

                    self.showViewController(homeViewController, sender: self)

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the class instead of an instance. Instead, you should pass the response instance to your `HomeViewController`:

```
class HomeViewController : .. {
  // ...
  var loginResponse : LoginResponse
  // ...

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    // ...
    bienvenueLabel.text = loginResponse.user.prenom
  }
}

  // ...
  client.login(code_perm, nip: nip, callback: { (response) in
            if let loginResponse = response as LoginResponse {

                    self.loadingLogin.stopAnimating()
                    let homeViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as HomeViewController

                    homeViewController.loginResponse = loginResponse
                    // assign your instance ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

                    self.showViewController(homeViewController, sender: self)

            }
```

---

This really isn't very good structure, but it should at least answer your question.